# I can't click and type on the form input feild Nextjs 13.4 and i don't know why

Tags: forms, input, next.js13

This is some of the code just a form some input feilds. Maybe the problem is somewhere here i can't figure it out but the input field is not clickable. If i get it to click i will be fine

```
  <form>
      <input
        id="email"
        value={email}
        name="email"
        type="email"
        autoComplete="off"
        placeholder="Enter Your Email"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        className="w-full text-xs p-3 h-8 my-2 outline-none rounded-md border focus:shadow-sm"
      />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="subject"
        value={subject}
        name="subject"
        onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
        autoComplete="off"
        placeholder="Subject"
        className="w-full text-xs p-3 h-8 my-2 outline-none rounded-md border focus:shadow-sm"
      />
 </form>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.